# Echo value into iframe url that is already in an iframe

Tags: php, session, iframe, echo

Is there anyway to echo values into an iframe that is already inside an iframe?

I need to echo from the parent url 2 stages down into the 2nd iframe.  The values in the parent are held as a php session.

Answer (score 0):

Try, like

```
<?php
   $id=1;
?>
<iframe src="page.php?id='<?php echo $id; ?>'" style=""></iframe>
```

In page.php

```
<?php
$id= $_GET['id'];
?>
 <iframe src="pages.php?id='<?php echo $id; ?>'" style=""></iframe>
```

Comment: or better check `isset($_GET['id'])`